# React multiple states reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bunch of state variables and I separated them instead of making an object. I don't know if this is the right way to go but I have a function that calculates and sets state variables based on a num input state that changes:

```
  const [isLow, setIsLow] = useState(false);
  const [isMedium, setIsMedium] = useState(false);
  const [isLarge, setIsLarge] = useState(false);
  const [isInfinite, setIsInfinite] = useState(false);

  function handleNum() {
    
    if (num < 120) {
      setIsLow(true);
    } else if (num < 320) {
      setIsMedium(true);
    } else if (num < 600) {
      setIsLarge(true);
    } else if (num >= 600) {
      setIsInfinite(true);
    }

    setCurrentNum(num);
  }
```

My problem is that is the first num is 9, then I change it to 500. The states isLarge and isLow are both true. I don't want to set every other state to false in each if statement so is there a better way? The only other thing, I can think of, is using an object for state but it doesn't seem right. it feels like it would be expensive. I haven't used reducers before but would this be a good case to use one?

Answer (score 1):

If `isLow`, `isMedium`, etc are always exclusively dependent on the value of `num`, then you don't need to use state for those variables. You can just assign them directly in the body of the function component.

```
const isLow = (num < 120);
const isMedium = (mum >= 120 && num < 320);
const isLarge = (num >= 320 && num < 600);
const isLarge = (num >= 600);
```

Comment: I use those values outside of my component thats why they are in state

Comment: @ousmane784 I'm not sure I understand. In this case you can use `isLow`, `isMedium`, etc. wherever you would normally use state variables.

Comment: I think what @ousmane784 means is that he is passing the state as props to other components

Comment: Your approach would be declaring variables within the function handleNum(). You cant use those outside of the function

Comment: @ousmane784 You might want to re-read the answer - I am suggesting doing that directly in the body of the function component. Thus removing the need for a `handleNum` function entirely.

Answer (score -1):

you can use multiple states but it would become complex as your application grows.

while using your approach, what I would do is when setting one state to true, I would set other states to false.

```
const [isLow, setIsLow] = useState(false);
const [isMedium, setIsMedium] = useState(false);
const [isLarge, setIsLarge] = useState(false);
const [isInfinite, setIsInfinite] = useState(false);
    
function handleNum() {
        
if (num < 120) {
  setIsLow(true);
  setIsMedium(false);
  setIsLarge(false);
} else if (num < 320) {
  setIsMedium(true);
  setIsLow(false);
  setIsHigh(false);
} else if (num < 600) {
  setIsLarge(true);
  setIsLow(false);
  setIsMedium(false);
} else if (num >= 600) {
  setIsInfinite(true);
  setIsLow(false);
  setIsMedium(false);
  setIsLarge(false);
}
   
  setCurrentNum(num);
}
```

Like this.

Comment: Yes I said that in my original question I am looking for a better way to handle this